# $_SESSION variable stays empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm creating a login script. The headers are all working but apparently the $_SESSION stays empty. Does anyone knows why this might be?

```
$db = dbConnection();

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername= $_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword= md5($_POST['mypassword']); 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM " .$members. " WHERE BINARY `username`= '".$myusername."' and BINARY `password`= '".$mypassword."'";
$result = $db->query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=$result->rowCount();

// Fetch this accounts row from db
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['privileges'] = $row['privileges'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
header("location:index.php");
```

}

Comment: Assuming you have `session_start();` hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `session_start()` at the top of your script.

Comment: 9 times out of 10, OP turns around and says "It's in my connections file". I never answer questions like these. They fall into the `C.O.W.` code category.

Comment: session_start(); is called in the index.php where it headers to. But it should be called before setting the $_SESSION variables indeed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not 3 seconds before I wrote that, there comes the OP and writes just what I said. I knew it.

Comment: just because it's called doesn't mean much. it has to be called PROPERLY - before **ANY** output is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities here either `session_start();` is not used or $count is not equal to 1 may be both are missing.